# Changing the format of CakePHP's CakeTime methods

Tags: php, cakephp, datetime, overriding

OOP noob here. I'd like to take advantage of CakePHP 2.3's short date methods in order to get "today" or "yesterday" when appropriate while changing the format of the date when the output is not "today" or "yesterday".

Example view: `echo $this->Time->niceShort($user['User']['last_invited_on'];`.

I've found the following in `lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.php` (Cake's `TimeHelper` uses the `CakeTime` utility.):

```
class CakeTime {

/**
 * The format to use when formatting a time using `CakeTime::nice()`
 *
 * The format should use the locale strings as defined in the PHP docs under
 * `strftime` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)
 *
 * @var string
 * @see CakeTime::format()
 */
    public static $niceFormat = '%a, %b %eS %Y, %H:%M';

/**
 * The format to use when formatting a time using `CakeTime::timeAgoInWords()`
 * and the difference is more than `CakeTime::$wordEnd`
 *
 * @var string
 * @see CakeTime::timeAgoInWords()
 */
    public static $wordFormat = 'j/n/y';

/**
 * The format to use when formatting a time using `CakeTime::niceShort()`
 * and the difference is between 3 and 7 days
 *
 * @var string
 * @see CakeTime::niceShort()
 */
    public static $niceShortFormat = '%B %d, %H:%M';
```

Can I somehow override this class's public properties in order to change the outputted date format whenever `Time->niceShort` is used in a view? (Is this "monkey patching"?) If so, what would be a good/clean way?

Or should I write a new class that extends `CakeTime`, and would this mean having to change `$this->Time` to `$this->MyNewSpiffingCustomisedTime` in views (which I'd rather not do as other people who are used to using Cake's `Time` are working on the project)? I wondered if this would be overkill just to change a property.

Comment: not ideal to change the library code. create your class and basically extend

Comment: Create new helper and extends new helper with cakephp built-in helper..

Answer (score 0):

**Old:**
No need, you could just compare:

```
if (date('Y-m-d') != $date && date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')) != $date) {
    //something
    echo $this->Time->niceShort($date);
    //something
}
```

`Y-m-d` is whatever your date format is i.e. `Y-m-d H:i:s`

**New:**
The proper way would be to call CakePHP wrapper for `date('format', strtotime($date));`. The CakePHP wrapper is defined as `$this->Time->format('format', $date);` and calls the previous php function I listed.

You shouldn't personalize base code if you plan to upgrade at any point. The only way (that I can think of right now) to still call $this->Time and extend the base code would be to implement a plugin called `Time` and include in your `$helper` and/or `$component` member variables `Time.mySpiffyTimeThingo` where mySpiffyTimeThingo is the name of the component or helper. These could extend/overwrite the current CakePHP CakeTime functions.

Comment: That seems to be more to do with determining when a date is today/yesterday rather than changing the format of the outputted date?

Comment: Are you saying you'd like it to display more like Today, time & Yesterday, time for every instance? e.g. 1 week ago, time; Last year, time?

Comment: No; see first paragraph in original question. I've also reworded the last couple of paragraphs to make clearer. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to be closer to what you were looking for, I think. Your question is still (at least to myself) no entirely clear so I'm taking a stab in the dark at the complete topic.

Comment: NOTE: As of the current version of CakePHP (2.6.x) the correct order of the parameters for TimeHelper::format() is the opposite of what's shown above. Should be `$timestamp, 'format_string``. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::format

Answer (score 0):

Why not extend the helper?

Create a class in `app/View/Helper/myTimeHelper.php`. In there add the reference to the old class you'll be extended like:

```
App::uses('TimeHelper', 'View/Helper');

class myTimeHelper extends TimeHelper {
    public function niceShort(<whatever input the original is getting>) {
        // your new logic for the things you want to change
        // and/or a return TimeHelper::niceShort(<whatever>) for the cases that are
        //fine as they are. If you don't need that then you can remove App::uses.
}
```

Finally you can have your helper imported as `myTime` with

```
public $helpers = array('myTime');
```

or even change the default `Time` to call `myTime` so you don't need to change anything else in your already written code:

```
public $helpers = array('Time' => array('className' => 'myTime'));
```